# Filter a dataframe using two conditions in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, filter

I want to filter a dataframe using two different condition.

But I want to omit rows which doesn't satisfy the condition and only want to keep values which occur at least twice in column A

[image: so this is the sample data]

```
df1 = df[(df['A-B occurrence'] >= 3) & (df['A occurrence'] >= 2)]
```

Above is the code I am using and this is the output I get:

[image]

So as in column A, 17 is satisfying condition in one row only so I want to omit 17 all together as it is not meeting the condition, which means I only want to keep duplicate values which are present in column A 2 or more than 2 times

Comment: "so as in coloumn A, 17 is satisfying condition in one row only" is not True. `'A occurrence' >= 2)`

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean.

Do you want an 'or' statement rather than an `and'?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, row 17 in `df` was filtered out.

Comment: I think OP wants to keep only the duplicated As (see my answer)

Comment: i dont want to filter out row 17 but 17 number

Comment: @GauravRaina so, A=19 should also be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you want to keep only the rows for which `A` has duplicates.

You can use:

```
df2 = df1[df1['A'].duplicated(keep=False)]
```

output: *this should remove rows with index 14 (A=17) and 19 (A=19)*

*NB. you can apply the same strategy on the other columns if needed*